# fix banner while scrolling a list view in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make an app. in this app there is a list view. while i scrolling list view a fixed banner exists. this banner doesn't changed until I bought a full version of that app. what is that banner? how can I defined it?

Comment: what is the banner that you are talking about??

Comment: I mean something like fixed banner while scrolling list view

Comment: u can create a layout and fix it at the bottom of your screen and u can place your listview above that layout.

Comment: this banner should be in the middle of screen. @Neha

Comment: ok then take a frame layout...and in  the same layout put your listview and banner layout..and set it in the center of the screen

Comment: thanks. i will try it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look after this link [Google Banner Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en)